# Is it best to have noise on the training set or the testing set?

Tags: self-study, classification, noise

Classification algorithms rely on a set of instances in order to obtain a classification model. Often, instances contain noise. Is it best to have noise on the training set or the testing set?

Comment: Is it a test or homework question? If so, please add `[self-study]` tag and see http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info

Comment: A statistical classifier like maxent, then there is the *expectation* that both sets of instances will have noise on the output because the objective function implies a conditionally multinomial/binomial distribution of label errors, but *no* noise on the predictors. Which sort of noise are you asking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your training and your testing set should be as similar as possible. Otherwise, the training set will not do a good job in training your model for the test set.

If your testing set contains more noise than the training set, your predictions will be worse than you expected - you will be too optimistic. Conversely, if your training set contains more noise than the test set, you will be pessimistic about your likely classification accuracy (and your model will be highly variable).

Finally, you will usually not be in a position to choose the noise level of either your training or your test set. You will aim at getting a training set that will be as similar to the test set as possible, and then try to understand *both* as much as possible, that is, to reduce noise in both sets as far as possible.